# S3 objects not expiring using the Golang SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Using the AWS Golang SDK, I'm attempting to set an expiration date for some of the objects that I'm uploading.  I'm pretty sure that the header is being set correctly, however, when logging into S3 and viewing the properties of the new object, it doesn't appear to have a expiration date.

Below is a snippet of how I'm uploading objects

```
exp := time.Now()
exp = exp.Add(time.Hour * 24)

svc := s3.New(session.New(config))
_, err = svc.PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket:        aws.String("MyBucketName"),
    Key:           aws.String("201700689.zip"),
    Body:          fileBytes,
    ContentLength: aws.Int64(size),
    ContentType:   aws.String(fileType),
    Expires:       &exp,
})
```

And here is what I see when logging into the site
[image]

Any idea what is going on here?  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `Expires` is just the wrong field:

> // The date and time at which the object is no longer cacheable.

What you want is `Object Expiration` which can be set as a bucket rule and not per object.

Basically, you add a Lifecycle rule (on the bucket properties) specifying:

> Each rule has the following attributes:
>
> Prefix – Initial part of the key name, (e.g. logs/), or the entire key name. Any object in the bucket with a matching prefix will be subject to this expiration rule. An empty prefix will match all objects in the bucket.
>
> Status – Either Enabled or Disabled. You can choose to enable rules from time to time to perform deletion or garbage collection on your buckets, and leave the rules disabled at other times.
>
> Expiration – Specifies an expiration period for the objects that are subject to the rule, as a number of days from the object’s creation date.
>
> Id – Optional, gives a name to the rule.

This rule will then be evaluated daily and any expired objects will be removed.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/ for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Much appreciated.  Hate to be the guy that didn't read / understand the docs

Answer (score 4):

One way to expire objects in S3 using Golang SDK is to tag your upload with something like

`Tagging: aws.String("temp=true")`

Then, Go to S3 Bucket Managment Console and Set a LifeCycle Rule **targeting for that specific ta**g like this.

[image]

You can configure the time frame to expire the object during the creation of the Rule in LifeCycle.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `s3.PresignOptions.Expires`, like this:

```golang
func PreSignPutObject(cfg aws.Config, bucket, objectKey string) (string, error) {
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    psClient := s3.NewPresignClient(client)

    input := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: &bucket,
        Key:    &objectKey,
    }
    resp, err := psClient.PresignPutObject(context.Background(), input, func(options *s3.PresignOptions){
        options.Expires = 3600 * time.Second
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return resp.URL, nil
}
```